# Envers - NonUniqueResultException when auditing a one-to-one association

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one, audit, hibernate-envers

I have a one-to-one association between class A and class B mapped as following :

```
     `  public class A implements Serializable {
           private B b;

           @OneToOne(mappedBy = "A", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
           public B getB() {
             return b;
           }

           public void setB(B b) {
             this.b = b;
           }
}`

`public class B implements Serializable{
    private A a;

   @OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.LAZY,optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false, unique = true)
    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}`
```

Each one has it's own audit table a_audit and b_audit. When I change the association, b_audit still refers to old deleted entities (which is normal and well desired).

When I try to retieve the audit of class A which also triggers the audit of the association with class B), I got the following error:

```
`
Caused by: javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractAuditQuery.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.OneToOneNotOwningMapper.queryForReferencedEntity(OneToOneNotOwningMapper.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.AbstractOneToOneMapper.nullSafeMapToEntityFromMap(AbstractOneToOneMapper.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.relation.AbstractToOneMapper.mapToEntityFromMap(AbstractToOneMapper.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.MultiPropertyMapper.mapToEntityFromMap(MultiPropertyMapper.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.mapper.SubclassPropertyMapper.mapToEntityFromMap(SubclassPropertyMapper.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.envers.internal.entities.EntityInstantiator.createInstanceFromVersionsEntity(EntityInstantiator.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.list(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getResultList(AbstractAuditQuery.java:109
`
```

Here is how I get the audit :

```
`
AuditQuery auditQuery = auditReader.createQuery()
                                                 .forRevisionsOfEntity(ClassA, false, true)
                                                 .add(AuditEntity.id()
                                                                 .in(entityId));
`
```

The is no duplication in revision number. The error disappear when I delete the old associations from the audit table.

EDIT:
My two classes are audited and I don't want to change this.
It will be OKAY if I can retrieve the audit of table A without the history of the association.

Your help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Hey, did you ever solve this?
I am currently stuck with on the same issue...

Comment: We didn't find any solution related to hibernate, so we just modified our conception by deleting the constraint not null on the 'a' column and set the 'a' value to null before deleting object b.